# How to validate authentication header in multiple functions in PHP

Tags: php, authentication, authorization

I'm trying to use `JWT` to create a authentication system using AngularJs and PHP. I understood the concept of `JWT`, I can modify the `headers` and send my access token, etc... My doubt is on the logic to elaborate this since I have a lot of different functions.

For example, I have a file called `client.php` where I have client related functions, such as `getClient`, `updateClient`, `insertClient`, etc.. The same applies for other files, `product.php`, `category.php`, `filter.php` and so on.

---

So, how am i supposed to do this token validation before actually running any of these functions?

I tought of creating a common function and use it inside each function, for example:

*function.php*

```
function checkToken($token) {
    $serverToken = //getting server token;
    if($token !== $serverToken) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

*client.php*

```
require_once 'function.php';
$tokenError = array('status' => 'Unauthorized');

function insertClient() {
    global $tokenError;

    $accessToken = $_SERVER['HTTP_TOKEN'];

    if(!checkToken($accessToken)) {
        return $tokenError;
    } else {
        //Proceed with the function
    }
}
function getClient() {
    //Repeat samething as insertClient
    //...
}
```

But it doesn't feel like the proper way to do this. So, is there a better, or a correct way, to do headers validation/authorization on each http request the user make?

Comment: Create a base class as your "Middleware" and you can check your validation code in your baseclass constructor.

Comment: How about use a class? Or at the top of your script check the auth token and the proceed to include other scripts.

Comment: @Blake would you mind providing an example?

Comment: @bassxzero could you show me an example? Because I had difficulties trying to achieve something like this

Comment: @CelsomTrindade I'd recommend some good reading on PHP Object oriented programming. Specifically classes, extending classes, and constructors.

Comment: @Blake I was reading some articles, and I think I'm getting the idea. But even when using class, the main idea is the same I proposed on the question, am I right? I'll have a central function to deal this verification, and I need to check it on each correspondent function, right?